# Is there a command to wrap a characters in a word using Emacs? Or something to insert "/" around a word while using org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, wrapping, words

In `org-mode`, writing a word wrapped by `/` makes it italic. For instance, `/word/` becomes *word*.

Is there a command in Emacs to make something go from `ẁord` to `/word/`?
Maybe some org related command only to do this?

Comment: The right way of implementing this would be to add this rule to org's syntax table I think. For example if you select a word in org mode and hit `"`, it will encircle it with the quotes. Take a look at `

Comment: AFAICT, this behavior of `"` and such is only available if you have enabled `electric-pair-mode` or its local equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As usual, Org has you covered: `org-emphasize`, bound by default to `C-c C-x C-f`.

This will work for all emphasis markers.  So, for italics, select the word and `C-c C-x C-f /`.

Comment: That's neat. In my humble opinion, the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

When `electric-pair-mode` is on, the following syntax rule suffices:

```lisp
(modify-syntax-entry ?/ "(/")
```

Notice that such rules should be added to `org-mode` only.

Comment: How exactly does this work? AFAICT, it does not for me, but I'm not sure what I am supposed to do. Can you explain? Do you have some sort of electric pair mode turned on? If so, your answer needs to be qualified.

Comment: @NickD, thank you for your clarification. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I still think your second point is wrong: modifying the syntax table causes complaints about unbalanced parentheses when a `/` is typed, but there is no insertion of anything extra. Have you tried it with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: You're correct. Edited again.

Answer (score 1):

The [wrap-region](https://github.com/rejeep/wrap-region.el) package does this. You can install it from MELPA.

Once you have it installed, you can add wrappers for org:

```lisp
(wrap-region-add-wrappers
 '(("*" "*" nil org-mode)
   ("/" "/" nil org-mode)
   ("~" "~" nil org-mode)
   ("+" "+" nil org-mode)))
```

You turn it on with `M-x wrap-region-mode`, or `M-x wrap-region-global-mode` if you want it for every buffer. Once it's on, if you select a word (or sentence or ...) and press one of the 'wrapper' keys, the characters will be added to the beginning and end of the active region. See the link above for details about customization for different modes.